# Remove elements from List A that are in List B while keeping any duplicates in List A

Tags: c#

I have a List A of strings that I want to trim of all elements that also appear in List B, while keeping the duplicate values in List A.
Such that with an input like:

```
List A: [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7]
List B: [2, 6, 8, 9, 10]
```

I am hoping to get an output like:

```
List C: [1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 7, 7, 7]
```

I originally thought this could be accomplished using ListA.Except(ListB), but that function leaves only one element of a duplicate value.

In the program, List B is much bigger than the example given and there are multiple instances of List A to go through, so I'd like to avoid nested for loops. I don't necessarily care about keeping the original order of List A either, since the output of this will be the input of a frequency dictionary.

Am I overlooking something? Is there a faster option than using nested for loops?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! What did you try, please update post so we can further help you with your issue.

Comment: The `List<T>.RemoveAll()` method does exactly what you want. You should put the elements of "List B" into a `HashSet<T>` so that the `Contains()` check for the `RemoveAll()` predicate is fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [List<T>.RemoveAll()](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall?view=netframework-4.7.2&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DDE-DE%26k%3Dk(System.Collections.Generic.List%601.RemoveAll);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```
  var a = new[] { 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7 }.ToList();
  var b = new[] { 2, 6, 8, 9, 10 }.ToList();
  var c = a.Select(i => i).ToList(); //make a copy of 'a'
  c.RemoveAll(i => b.Contains(i));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a `Where()` clause with a `Contains()` in it. To avoid `O(n²)` complexity (which is really what you're trying to avoid when you say "nested for loops," you can create a HashSet out of List B.

```
var setB = listB.ToHashSet();
var aMinusB = listA.Where(item => !setB.Contains(item)).ToList();
```

Comment: @zaggler: Duplicates in the output are exactly what the OP is asking for. They're complaining that `Except()` removes those duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LINQ` for this using `any`:

```
var result = listA.Where(el1 => !listB.Any(el2 => el2 == el1)).ToList();
```